# What's a good alternative to PAUSE for use in the implementation of a spinlock?

Tags: c++, concurrency, x86-64, spinlock, energy

I am working on making a fiber-based job system for my latest project which will depend on the use of spinlocks for proper functionality. I had intended to use the PAUSE instruction as that seems to be the gold-standard for the waiting portion of your average modern spinlock. However, on doing some research into implementing my own fibers, I came across the fact that the cycle duration of PAUSE on recent machines has increased to an adverse extent.

I found this out from [here](https://graphitemaster.github.io/fibers/), where it says, quoting the Intel Optimization Manual, "The latency of PAUSE instruction in prior generation microarchitecture is about 10 cycles, whereas on Skylake microarchitecture it has been extended to as many as 140 cycles," and
"As the PAUSE latency has been increased significantly, workloads that are sensitive to PAUSE latency will suffer some performance loss."

As a result, I'd like to find an alternative to the PAUSE instruction for use in my own spinlocks. I've read that in the past, PAUSE has been preferred due to it somehow saving on energy usage which I'm guessing is due to the other often quoted factoid that using PAUSE somehow signals to the processor that it's in the midst of a spinlock. I'm also guessing that this is on the other end of the spectrum power-wise to doing some dummy calculation for the desired number of cycles.

Given this, is there a best-case solution that comes close to PAUSE's apparent energy efficiency while having the flexibility and low-cycle count as a repeat 'throwout' calculation?

Comment: Why not just write readable, standard compliant C++ and turn on your compilers optimizer and let it worry about it? In short; "why bother"? Are you *really* in a situation where you can measure an actual difference between handwritten asm and compiler optimized code and where it actually matters?

Comment: @JesperJuhl AFAIK C++ doesn't include a user-accessible spinlock implementation.  (As for "why use a spinlock at all?", the answer is usually that you are operating in a real-time context where standard synchronization primitives like mutexes aren't allowed)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Real time context need for spinlocks might be a reasonable explanation. *Might be* - but I don't even see that in the question.

Comment: *"workloads that are sensitive to PAUSE latency will suffer some performance loss."*  And you intend to introduce workloads that *are* sensitive? How does one do that?

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/clamav/clamav-158/clamav.Bin/clamav-0.98/win32/3rdparty/pthreads/pthread_spin_lock.c.auto.html which you can also make with `std::atomic_flag` and calling `test_and_set` on it, then using `nanosleep` if necessary.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Currently all of the code, including the spinlock, is written in C++.  The reading I've done on the subject has "PAUSE():" synonymous with "_mm_pause();" though perhaps there's some contention that I'm unaware about between this interpretation of PAUSE and what led to the belief I was writing in ASM.

Comment: @BoP This is my first rodeo with any sort of serious approach to concurrency, so I figured I would seek after something that can handle whatever workload I throw at it rather than some suffering due to the PAUSE latency. However, after thinking about it some more, workloads that would suffer from this would occur when the amount of time doing useful work approaches the time taken in the spinlock, right? In which case the choice of work I'm having this system do would be more problematic than the choice of whether or not to use PAUSE / which substitute I swap it out for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm guessing is due to the other often quoted factoid that using PAUSE somehow signals to the processor that it's in the midst of a spinlock.

Yes, `pause` lets the CPU avoid memory-order mis-speculation when leaving a read-only spin-wait loop, which is how you should spin to avoid creating contention for the thread trying to unlock that location.  (Don't spam `xchg`).  See also:

- [How does x86 pause instruction work in spinlock *and* can it be used in other scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725676/how-does-x86-pause-instruction-work-in-spinlock-and-can-it-be-used-in-other-sc)
- [Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure? If not, is it better than xchg for spinlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008857/does-cmpxchg-write-destination-cache-line-on-failure-if-not-is-it-better-than) - spin read-only (with `pause`) if the first atomic RMW fails to take the lock.  You do want to start with an RMW attempt so you don't get a Shared copy of the cache line and then have to wait for another off-core request; if the first access is an RMW like `xchg` or `lock cmpxchg`, the first request the core makes will be an RFO.
- [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241553/locks-around-memory-manipulation-via-inline-assembly/37246263#37246263) a minimal x86 asm spinlock using `pause` (but no fallback to OS-assisted sleep/wake, so inappropriate if the locking thread might ever sleep while holding the lock.)

If you have to wait for another core to change something in memory, it doesn't help much to check much more frequently than the inter-core latency, especially if you'll stall right when you finally do see the change you've been waiting for.

---

#### Dealing with `pause` being slow (newer Intel) or fast (AMD and old Intel)

If you have code that uses multiple `pause` instructions between checking the shared value, you should change the code to do fewer.

See also [Why have AMD-CPUs such a silly PAUSE-timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331846/why-have-amd-cpus-such-a-silly-pause-timing) with Brendan's suggestion of checking `rdtsc` in spin loops to better adapt to unknown delays from `pause` on different CPUs.

Basically try to make your workload *not* as sensitive to `pause` latency.  That may also mean trying to avoid waiting for data from other threads as much, or having other useful work to do until a lock becomes available.

---

#### Alternatives, IDK if this is lower wakeup latency than spinning with `pause`

On CPUs new enough to have the WAITPKG extension (Tremont or Alder Lake / Sapphire Rapids), `umonitor` / [`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) could be viable to wait in user-space for a memory location to change, like spinning but the CPU wakes itself up when it sees cache coherency traffic about a change, or something like that.  Although that may be slower than `pause` if it has to enter a sleep state.

(You can ask [`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) to only go into C0.1, not C0.2, with bit 0 of the register you specify, and EDX:EAX as a TSC deadline.  Intel says a C0.2 sleep state improves performance of the other hyperthread, so presumably that means switching back to single-core-active mode, de-partitioning the store-buffer, ROB, etc., and having to wait for re-partitioning before this core can wake up.  But C0.1 state doesn't do that.)

---

**Even in the worst case, `pause` is only about 140 core clock cycles.**  That's still much faster than a Linux system call on a modern x86-64, especially with Spectre / Meltdown mitigation.  (Thousands to tens of thousands of clock cycles, up from a couple hundred just for `syscall` + `sysret`, let alone calling `schedule()` and maybe running something else.)

So if you're aiming to minimize wakeup latency at the expense of wasting CPU time spinning longer, `nanosleep` is not an option.  If might be good for other use-cases though, as a fallback after spinning on `pause` a couple times.

Or use `futex` to sleep on a value changing or on a notify from another process.  (It doesn't guarantee that the kernel will use `monitor` / `mwait` to sleep until a change, it will let other tasks run.  So you do need to have the unlocking thread make a `futex` system call if any waiters had gone to sleep with `futex`.  But you can still make a lightweight mutex that avoids any system calls in the locker and unlocker if there isn't contention and no threads go to sleep.)

But at that point, with `futex` you're probably reproducing what glibc's `pthread_mutex` does.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response!

Answer (score 0):

I can only refer you to [this talk](https://youtu.be/rmGJc9PXpuE) by Fedor Pikus. In this he claims that (on linux) `nanosleep` is generally the fastest on most systems. The real answer though, is to benchmark different implementations, and see whichever is fastest!

Comment: Upvote for the "benchmark it" bit.

Comment: If a `pause` instruction is too slow on Skylake, at up to 140 core clock cycles, there's no way a `syscall` is going to be acceptable!!! The round trip to kernel mode and back is at least a couple hundred cycles.  But with Spectre / Meltdown mitigation enabled, the kernel is doing to do a bunch of stuff in the `syscall` entry point like changing page tables and invalidating branch history, taking thousands or tens of thousands of cycles for the cheapest system call.

Comment: If you were going to make any system call in a spinlock, you'd probably use `futex` to let the kernel wake you up when the value of that memory location changed.  (Or when another process did a futex notify upon unlocking, if the kernel wasn't sleeping on a `monitor`/`mwait` on that address when it changed, if that's even something Linux will do.)  Speaking of which, on CPUs new enough to have it, `umonitor` / `umwait` could be viable to wait for a memory location to change in user-space.